# How to install psycopg2 on clean OS X Lion with Xcode 4.1

Tags: django, psycopg2, osx-lion

On a clean OS X Lion with Xcode 4.1 installed. PostgreSQL is already installed by Apple. I installed Django 1.3. The instruction for installing psycopg2 isn't clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which tutorial are you working with, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hmm. No that doesn't appear to work either unfortunately lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccsXSwZZ.out (No such file or directory) error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 3):

Try this to install psycopg2 on OS X Lion (hat tip to [Jeremy Bowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564713/jeremy-bowers)):

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I also needed to create a symlink to gcc-4.0:

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.0

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" make

sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" python ./setup.py install
```

did the job.

I had to set a link from `gcc-4.2` to `gcc` also.

Answer (score 0):

optional:
Install xcode 4.1 and then 4.2

Install Mac Ports ( www.macports.org )

in a virtualenv environment:
pip install psycopg2

outside virtualenv environment:
sudo port install psycopg2